# Generating combinations of data and then running Wilcoxon test on each combination

Tags: r

I have a data set that is composed of 50 students (rows) with 15 scores (columns, scores on a 1-5 scale) each and am trying to do a couple of things. First, I am trying to generate all possible combinations of 10 scores for each student from the original 15. Then, I am trying to run a Wilcoxon test (I believe Mann-Whitney U) for each score combination against the original set of 15 scores for the students to determine which combinations are significantly different. The code in R that I have made thus far is posted below with the loop to run the test on each combination, but I keep getting the error 'error not enough (finite) observations', and I am not sure if I am doing it appropriately. I tried as.numeric() and that still did not seem to fix it. The code seems to generate the combinations fine, I just can't get the test to work. All help is appreciated, totally prepared to be told I am doing it incorrectly, and wisdom on de-cluttering the code would be much appreciated.

```
m<-10
n<-choose(15,m)

for(j in 1:50)
{df3 <- expand.grid(combn(data[j,],m))  

x<-(length = 0)    

for(i in 1:n)    
{niceArray <- c(df3[1,(m*(i-1)+1)],df3[1,(m*(i-1)+2)],df3[1,(m*(i-  1)+3)],df3[1,(m*(i-1)+4)],df3[1,(m*(i-1)+5)],df3[1,(m*(i-1)+6)],df3[1,(m*(i-1)+7)],df3[1,(m*(i-1)+8)],df3[1,(m*(i-1)+9)],df3[1,(m*(i-1)+10)])

tst<-wilcox.test(niceArray, as.numeric(data[j,]), alternative="two.sided", paired=FALSE)
if(tst$p.value<0.05)
{print(tst$p.value)    
x<-append(x,1,after=length(x))}}
print(length(x)-1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

So it was a little hard to parse through what you did. Here is what I did to try to solve your problem.

I first created a dataset with 2 students that had 15 scores.

```
student_ds<-rbind(abs(sample(rnorm(15)*100)),abs(sample(rnorm(15)*100)))
```

I then create an empty dataset called testresults.
Inside the loop we create a dataframe with all possible combinations of 10 from the 15 scores. Then we use apply to get the wilcoxon p-value for comparing the original student's 15 scores to all possible 3003 scores and append it to the subsample. Last we bind these together in the testresults dataframe.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(student_ds)){
  combinatoric<-data.frame(t(combn(student_ds[i,],10)))  # represents all ways to choose 10 from the 15
  combinatoric$wilcox.pvalue<- apply(combinatoric[,1:10],1,function(x) wilcox.test(x,student_ds[i,], alternative="two.sided", paired=FALSE)$p.value)
  combinatoric$student <- paste0("student",i)
  testresults <- rbind(testresults,combinatoric)  
  }

> head(testresults);tail(testresults)
        X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6       X7       X8       X9        X10 wilcox.pvalue  student
1 1.974715 72.51776 119.8322 12.26869 85.91388 209.4265 65.30297 17.25499 27.32821  79.272713     0.8894956 student1
2 1.974715 72.51776 119.8322 12.26869 85.91388 209.4265 65.30297 17.25499 27.32821  80.104210     0.9335609 student1
3 1.974715 72.51776 119.8322 12.26869 85.91388 209.4265 65.30297 17.25499 27.32821  93.908482     1.0000000 student1
4 1.974715 72.51776 119.8322 12.26869 85.91388 209.4265 65.30297 17.25499 27.32821 107.429904     0.9778308 student1
5 1.974715 72.51776 119.8322 12.26869 85.91388 209.4265 65.30297 17.25499 27.32821  50.930822     0.7598532 student1
6 1.974715 72.51776 119.8322 12.26869 85.91388 209.4265 65.30297 17.25499 27.32821   5.215228     0.5975122 student1
            X1        X2       X3       X4       X5       X6       X7       X8       X9      X10 wilcox.pvalue  student
6001  47.59236 222.62861  9.04522 78.70014 83.69301 123.9315 14.30569 40.72565 56.99276 129.4363     0.9778308 student2
6002  47.59236 222.62861  9.04522 78.70014 32.81073 123.9315 14.30569 40.72565 56.99276 129.4363     0.7598532 student2
6003  47.59236 222.62861  9.04522 83.69301 32.81073 123.9315 14.30569 40.72565 56.99276 129.4363     0.8025127 student2
6004  47.59236 222.62861 78.70014 83.69301 32.81073 123.9315 14.30569 40.72565 56.99276 129.4363     0.8894956 student2
6005  47.59236   9.04522 78.70014 83.69301 32.81073 123.9315 14.30569 40.72565 56.99276 129.4363     0.5595174 student2
6006 222.62861   9.04522 78.70014 83.69301 32.81073 123.9315 14.30569 40.72565 56.99276 129.4363     0.9335609 student2
```

If that isn't exactly what you want, it probably will be enough to spur you on to greatness.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure why you would want to do this. Please do inform :)